# Java xml parsing?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to read xml files. I can read and load xml files correctly. I just don't understand how do I read this,

```
<c c="6" r="182, 0, 192, 15" />
```

Ps: I am on phone, so dont know how to code format

Edit: the r is, x, y, width and height.
   Edit: is there any method in java xml that can read the r string as four different int or I have to do it manualy?

Thank you.

Comment: Whats the problem? It is a well-formed XML file.

Comment: *I can read and load xml files correctly.* Then what are you asking?

Comment: I am trying to read the r, which is four coordinate, x,y, width and height, which I am trying to assign on four int.

Comment: "r" is an attribute of "c". Are you getting the String (`"182, 0, 192, 15"`) back?

Comment: Yes, but these are four different values, how do I assign them to four different int.

Comment: You can use the method `split` in `String` class to separate r by the commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment (for splitting the integer values out of a single CSV list in an XML attribute), you could do it with something like -

```
String str = "182, 0, 192, 15";
String[] values = str.split(", ");
if (values.length >= 4) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(values[0].trim());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(values[1].trim());
    int width = Integer.parseInt(values[2].trim());
    int height = Integer.parseInt(values[3].trim());
    System.out.printf("x = %d, y = %d, width = %d, height = %d\n", x,
            y, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, sure, I will do.

Answer (score 0):

You have a tag "c" --
`Element maytag = yourdom.getElementByTagName("c");`

Which has attributes:

```
"c" with a value of "6"
```

`String six = mytag.getAttribute("c");`

"r" with a value of "182, 0, 192, 15"

```
String numlist = mytag.getAttribute("r");
```

After that you need some plain old Java to split up the string and parse the integers (see Elliot Frisch's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to parse it in some way.